# How to use bluebird promise for specific scenario

Tags: node.js, promise, bluebird

I need to use bluebird promise for following scenario (already implemented in native promise using sequential approach), but confuse how to do it in bluebird.

```
data : 
  [
     {
         field1 : value1,
         field2 : [
             subfield1 : subvalue1,
             subfield2 : subvalue2 
         ]
         field3 : value3,
     },
     {
         field1 : value1,
         field2 : [
             subfield1 : subvalue1,
             subfield2 : subvalue2 
         ]
         field3 : value3,
     }
  ]
```

- So I first I need a promise based parallel loop for each block
- In each block I need to perform four parallel separate function ( they have their own logic like http/db )
- Then I need fifth function which need data comes from one of above four functions
- Then I need save function
- Then same logic repeat for next block
- finally resolve promise

Currently I tried similar to following

```
var bbPromise = require("bluebird");

db.connect(dsn).then(prepareData).then( (results) => {

}).catch( (err) => {
    console.log(err)

});


function prepareData(dbObject) {

    let recordsToInsert = [];
    let promises = [];
    request.forEach(function(row, idx) {

        let procesedRow = {
            // data build from row
        };

        promises.push( childFunction(procesedRow));

    });

    bbPromise.all( promises).then( (results) => {
        // resolve here ?
    })
}

function childFunction(data) {
   bbPromise.join( 
        firstFunction(data), 
        secondFunction(data), 
        thirdFunction(data),
        fourthFunction(data)
    )
    .then( (results) => {
        data.firstResults = results[0];

        data.secondResults = results[1];

        data.thirdResults = results[2];

        data.fourthResults = results[3];

        return data;

    }).then( fifthFunction )
    .then( (results) => {
        data.fifthResults = results; 
        return insertData(data);
    })
    .then( (results) => {
        bbPromise.resolve(results);
    });
}
```

Its working but final successful call (See resolve here ?) executed before any of actual operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The import thing to understand is that promises are *result* values. You must not forget to `return` them, otherwise they will get ignored. You don't need to "resolve anything", all you need to do is `return` the promises and they will chain automatically:

```
function prepareData(dbObject) {
    let recordsToInsert = [];
    let promises = request.map(function(row, idx) {
//                         ^^^
        let procesedRow = {
            // data build from row
        };
        return childFunction(procesedRow);
//      ^^^^^^ (ok, `push` would've worked as well)
    });
    return bbPromise.all(promises);
//  ^^^^^^
}

function childFunction(data) {
    return bbPromise.join(
//  ^^^^^^
        firstFunction(data), 
        secondFunction(data), 
        thirdFunction(data),
        fourthFunction(data)
    ).then(results => {
        data.firstResults = results[0];
        data.secondResults = results[1];
        data.thirdResults = results[2];
        data.fourthResults = results[3];
        return data;
    }).then(fifthFunction).then(results => {
        data.fifthResults = results; 
        return insertData(data);
    });
}
```

Comment: Hmm its worked. Is their any specific case where we must use resolve instead of return ?

Comment: Inside a `new Promise` - i.e. almost never